# Linq command to find differences in Azure Table Storage entries

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I have an **Azure Table Storage** table with the structure:

```
id    date_changed    entity_1    entity_2
 1      May 1 2015        true       false
 2      May 2 2015       false        true
 3      May 3 2015       false       false
 4      May 4 2015        true       false
 5      May 5 2015       false        true
 6      May 7 2015        true       false
```

I am trying to find a way to pull out only those records which `entity_1` has changed over time (`date_changed`). *For instance*, if I want to return the records where `entity_1` changed from either `false → true` or `true → false` as `date_changed` increases:

```
 2      May 2 2015        false      true
 4      May 4 2015        true       false
 5      May 5 2015        false      true
 6      May 7 2015        true       false
```

Or for `entity_2`:

```
 2      May 2 2015        false      true
 3      May 3 2015        false      false
 5      May 5 2015        false      true
 6      May 7 2015        true       false
```

I can certainly do this with a loop, but that won't really scale since I'd have to iterate through all my records, and as my table increases records, this seems infeasible.

**Is there a way to create a Linq query to query Table storage to return only those records where `entity_1` or `entity_2` change as `date_changed` increases?**

Comment: Do you insert a record for each entity as the day changes? What I mean to ask is that today is 12th July. As the clock hits 13th July, do you insert a new record in the table for all the entities with their current state (true or false)? As the day progresses, if the entity status changes do you update those entities? Then on the next day, you insert new records again? Also please tell us about your PartitionKey/RowKey values.

Comment: Records are not necessarily inserted daily, but multiple records will *not* be inserted on the same day (ie., maybe every day, maybe every other day, etc). `PartitianKey` is a userid (so assume that the above example all have the same `PartitianKey`. `RowKey` is a simple `GUID`.

Comment: Here is an idea: you use entity ids as partition keys and inverse time (max time - current date) as row key. So each entity will end up in different partition and the recent update will be at the top always. Whenever you add a new update, have an extra field as an indicator of change. Your access to the most recent update will be really performant. Query among a set of partitions will have high throughput.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to implement the requested functionality with a key-value NoSQL database service like Azure Table in a scalable way. The solution I would recommend is creating two new tables, Entity1TransitionTable and Entity2TransitionTable. The proposal is to detect transitions on the fly and maintain the list of transitions in these tables under the premise Azure Table storage is relatively inexpensive. This solution assumes the application can always keep track of the ID value and that it always increments by 1.

```
  public class LogEntry : TableEntity
  {
     public LogEntry() { }
     public LogEntry(string userid, int id, string date, bool entity1, bool entity2)
     {
        PartitionKey = userid;
        RowKey = id.ToString();
        Id = id;
        Entity1 = entity1;
        Entity2 = entity2;
        Date = date;
     }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Date { get; set; } 
     public bool Entity1 { get; set; }         
     public bool Entity2 { get; set; }         
  }

  static void TransitionDetection(CloudTable tbl, CloudTable e1Tbl, CloudTable e2Tbl, LogEntry currentLogEntry)
  {
     if (currentLogEntry.Id> 1)
     {
        // Retrieve the previous log entry
        string pkFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, currentLogEntry.PartitionKey);
        string rkFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, (currentLogEntry.Id - 1).ToString());
        string combinedFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(pkFilter, TableOperators.And, rkFilter);
        TableQuery<LogEntry> query = new TableQuery<LogEntry>().Where(combinedFilter);
        LogEntry prevLogEntry = tbl.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList()[0];

        // If Entity1 transitioned, record it
        if (prevLogEntry.Entity1 != currentLogEntry.Entity1)
        {
           e1Tbl.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(currentLogEntry));
        }

        // If Entity2 transitioned, record it
        if (prevLogEntry.Entity2 != currentLogEntry.Entity2)
        {
           e2Tbl.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(currentLogEntry));
        }
     }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string storageConnection = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyTable;AccountKey=MY_KEY";

     // Select table
     CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
     CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
     CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("LogTable");
     CloudTable entity1TransitionTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("Entity1TransitionTable");
     CloudTable entity2TransitionTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("Entity2TransitionTable");
     table.CreateIfNotExists();
     entity1TransitionTable.CreateIfNotExists();
     entity2TransitionTable.CreateIfNotExists();

     // Add Log Entries
     int id = 0;

     LogEntry le1 = new LogEntry("0", ++id, "May 1 2015", true, false);
     TransitionDetection(table, entity1TransitionTable, entity2TransitionTable, le1);
     table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(le1));

     LogEntry le2 = new LogEntry("0", ++id, "May 2 2015", false, true);
     TransitionDetection(table, entity1TransitionTable, entity2TransitionTable, le2);
     table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(le2));

     LogEntry le3 = new LogEntry("0", ++id, "May 3 2015", false, false);
     TransitionDetection(table, entity1TransitionTable, entity2TransitionTable, le3);
     table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(le3));

     LogEntry le4 = new LogEntry("0", ++id, "May 4 2015", true, false);
     TransitionDetection(table, entity1TransitionTable, entity2TransitionTable, le4);
     table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(le4));

     LogEntry le5 = new LogEntry("0", ++id, "May 5 2015", false, true);
     TransitionDetection(table, entity1TransitionTable, entity2TransitionTable, le5);
     table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(le5));

     LogEntry le6 = new LogEntry("0", ++id, "May 7 2015", true, false);
     TransitionDetection(table, entity1TransitionTable, entity2TransitionTable, le6);
     table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(le6));

     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

If you examine the tables with an application like TableXplorer, you will observe the following results:

LogTable

[image]

Entity1TransitionTable

[image]

Entity2TransitionTable

[image]